# Oracle temp tablespace alter statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, ddl, tablespace

What is wrong with my query? I had look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles002.htm) but could not resolve the problem.

```
SQL> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMPRM;
```

Tablespace created.

```
SQL> ALTER  TABLESPACE  TEMPRM ADD DATAFILE   '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_temp01.dbf';
ALTER  TABLESPACE  TEMPRM ADD DATAFILE   '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_temp01.dbf'
*
ERROR at line 1: ORA-03217: invalid option for alter of TEMPORARY TABLESPACE
```

Comment: is +TEMPDATA a directory?? try once with size option in command.

Comment: use :- size 2M autoextend off; instead of 2M give value accordingly

Comment: Same error.ALTER  TABLESPACE  TEMPRM ADD DATAFILE   '+TEMPDATA/RM/DATAFILE/TEMPRM_temp01.dbf' SIZE 2M AUTOEXTEND OFF
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03217: invalid option for alter of TEMPORARY TABLESPACE

Comment: is the file name correct in ASM TEMPRM_temp01.dbf? check if this file exist in dba_temp_files table or in v$datafile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A temporary tablespace is made up of tempfiles, not datafiles, so:

```
ALTER  TABLESPACE TEMPRM ADD TEMPFILE '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/TEMPRM_temp01.dbf' SIZE 2G;
----------------------------- Here -^
```

Comment: It worked " ALTER  TABLESPACE  TEMPRM ADD TEMPFILE '+TEMPDATA/RM/DATAFILE/TEMPRM_temp01.dbf' SIZE 2M;"